# interpolation of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a sequence of iid, zero-mean and unit-variance Gaussian random variables. Let $Y(t), t\in\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous-time random process built by linear interpolation of $\{X_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$. What is the first order pdf of $Y(t)$, i.e., $f(y;t)$?

Amendment:

What if the $\{X_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an iid sequence of random variables uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

Let $\tau=t-\lfloor{t}\rfloor$. Then $Y(t)=(1-\tau)X(\lfloor t\rfloor)+\tau X(\lceil t\rceil)$. At any instance $t$, $Y(t)$ is a random variable with the characteristic function:

$$\Phi_{Y(t)}(\omega) = E\{ e^{j\omega Y(t)} \} = E\{ e^{j\omega [(1-\tau)X(\lfloor t\rfloor)+\tau X(\lceil t\rceil)]} \}$$

Since $X(\lfloor t\rfloor)$ and $X(\lceil t\rceil)$ are independent:

$$\Phi_{Y(t)}(\omega) = E\{ e^{j\omega [(1-\tau)X(\lfloor t\rfloor)}\} E\{e^{j\omega\tau X(\lceil t\rceil)]} \}$$

Let $f_X(x)$ and $\Phi_X(\nu)$ denote the pdf and the characteristic function of $X$, respectively. Then

$$ \Phi_{Y(t)}(\omega) = \Phi_X((1-\tau)\omega)) \Phi_X(\tau\omega))$$

Taking the inverse Fourier transform:

$$ f_Y(y;t) = \dfrac{1}{1-\tau}f_x\left(\dfrac{y}{1-\tau}\right) * \dfrac{1}{\tau}f_x\left(\dfrac{y}{\tau}\right)$$

where $*$ denotes the convolution operator.

If $X_k$'s are independent and zero-mean Gaussian, any $Y(t)$ is also a zero-mean Gaussian and it suffices to evaluate the variance at $t$. However, this approach does not work if they are not Gaussian. As for the amended part, where $X$'s are uniformly distributed as

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & 0<x<1\\
0 & \text{o.w.}\\
\end{cases}$$

for $\tau=t-\lfloor{t}\rfloor$, let $\alpha = \max\{\tau, 1-\tau\}$. So,

$$ f_Y(y;t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\tau}{\alpha(1-\alpha)} & 0<y<1-\alpha\\
\frac{1}{\alpha} & 1-\alpha<y<\alpha \\
\frac{1-\tau}{\alpha(1-\alpha)} & \alpha<y<1 \\
0 & \text{o.w.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
Y(t) = (\lfloor t \rfloor + 1 - t)X(\lfloor t \rfloor) + (t - \lfloor t \rfloor) X(\lfloor t\rfloor - 1)
$$
So
$$
Y(t) \sim \operatorname N(0, (\lfloor t\rfloor+1-t)^2 +(\lfloor t\rfloor - 1)^2 ).
$$

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering what if the sequence is iid uniform, so I updated the question.